# Extract a version number from bar-descriptor.xml file programatically

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

Is there a way to extract a version number and other information from `bar-descriptor.xml` file similar to how it's done in Android world via [getPackageInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) in [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason missed classes which allow to do this exactly:

- [PackageInfo](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__packageinfo.html)
- [ApplicaitonInfo](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__applicationinfo.html)